# How do you generate a QR code for a not so popular coin?

Tags: qrcode

I'm running a the datacoin-qt client and was wondering how do you generate a QR code? This is relatively a new coin and I can generate an address, but I'm not sure where I can goto to generate a QR code for this.

Comment: Here is simple and quick QR code generator: https://tool.tonytuan.org/#/QrCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any QR generator to create the image. Just select type "text", ECC level "H", and UTF-8 encoding. The QR codes are nothing more than the address.

I use http://goqr.me/ for a quick online generator. Otherwise Mikael's link works well from what I've heard.

Comment: so how does BIP32 come into play where its a password protected QR code.

Comment: The QR code is not itself password protected. BIP32 described HD Wallet formats, not itself a password protected format. Perhaps you mean that you have a BIP32 wallet, and you want to generate a QR code of the BIP38 protected master key? If that's the case, you'd simply generate the BIP32 MK, BIP38 encode it, and generate the same QR of the 6P text code output from the encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to just generate the QR code for one time use, or include the code generation into a program? If the latter you can use this for javascript: http://larsjung.de/qrcode/

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question i know, but u can use our simple new service http://my.walletco.de

It just takes 2 Clicks to generate your QR-Walletcode for almost every Cryptocurrency. We also put the Logo of the coin into the center of the generated QR-Code, so u can easy spot the Cryptocurency of that QR-Code.

[image: Generated QR-Code for cryptocurrency walletcode from my.walletco.de]

Comment: Everyone here should be warned, not to enter private key or other sensitive information. That adds to the reputation. I have checked the site with two or three (bitcoin) addresses, this was not a problem. So again, don't enter any private keys on such type of sites!